# Logging handler with timeout

Tags: python, logging, timeout

I'm searching for a solution to watch my python script if it's stuck. My idea is to use a logging handler with a timeout function. So if for a specific time no log message is printed, the script can be restarted. Currently I have no possibility to make sure if the script is running.

Is there an implementation of such a logging handler class?

Answer (score -1):

I think I found a solution...
I'm testing if it works

```
class TimeoutHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        signal.alarm(10*60)

    def handler(signum, frame):
        raise Exception("No log message for specified time")

    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
```